# CSS Animation Fade In Slide Down

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to recreate this flash animation into HTML/CSS but I got stuck.

This is the actual animation, the first image with dark background fades in, then the next image will  slide down

http://www.learner.org/series/econusa/interactivelabs/graphing-lab_moose-synthesizer-co/

Here's what I got so far... how can I add the second image to slide down?

http://jsfiddle.net/tetonline/QZNut/2/

HTML

```
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="https://tchuatocolearner.eppi.com/temp/graphinglab/images/blur.png" />
```

CSS

```
img {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
    /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 3s;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

Comment: Also when the user click on the 'let's begin' button, it will show another animation. Then the user will click on let's start button and it will go to a form (which I already made). Can all these sequence of animations happen in just one html document?

Comment: anything against js/jquery ?

Comment: aug my jsfiddle is open to public. I just signed up an hour ago and don't really know much about authentications

Comment: Patsy Issa I'm open to suggestion if the code is available.

Comment: It's your image urls - going to a private source: https://tchuatocolearner.eppi.com/temp/graphinglab/images/blur

Comment: yes it does. I just remembered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a rough version that you can work with that uses CSS3 animations along with two  javascript functions simply to add/remove the animation classes. [**Check it out here**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/wcqc0ejf)

This will perform better than a fully javascript/jQuery version.

Also, I recommend making the slide down elements `div`s as opposed to `img`s so you can have content within it like the buttons I added.

Here is the relevant code

```
<div id='firstDiv' class='overlay moveDown'>
  <button onclick='firstAction()'></button>
</div>
<div id='secondDiv' class='overlay'>
  <button onclick='secondAction()'></button>
</div> 
<div id='content' class='fadeMe'>...Content...</div>

// CSS
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:-500px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
    z-index:3;
}
@keyframes movedown {
    0% {
        top:-100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:50%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes movedown {
    0% {
        top:-100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:50%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes movedown {
    0% {
        top:-100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:50%;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes movedown {
    0% {
        top:-100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:50%;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes movedown {
    0% {
        top:-100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:50%;
    }
}

@keyframes moveup {
    0% {
        top:50%;
    }
    100% {
        top:-100%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveup {
    0% {
        top:50%;
    }
    100% {
        top:-100%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveup {
    0% {
        top:50%;
    }
    100% {
        top:-100%;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveup {
    0% {
        top:50%;
    }
    100% {
        top:-100%;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes moveup {
    0% {
        top:50%;
    }
    100% {
        top:-100%;
    }
}
#firstDiv {
    background-image: url(http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2013/pets/news/130304/kitten-3-600.jpg);
}
#secondDiv {
    background-image: url(http://wallpapersfor.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cute_cat_praying-1280x800.jpg);
} 
.moveDown {
  -webkit-animation: movedown 2s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: movedown 2s linear forwards;
  -ms-animation: movedown 2s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: movedown 2s linear forwards;
  animation: movedown 2s linear forwards;
  <!--
  animation-name:"movedown";
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -->
}
.moveUp {
  -webkit-animation: moveup 2s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: moveup 2s linear forwards;
  -ms-animation: moveup 2s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: moveup 2s linear forwards;
  animation: moveup 2s linear forwards;
  <!--
  animation-name:"moveup";
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -->
}
#content {
  padding:40px;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:75%;
  height:75%;
  opacity:1;
  transition:2s opacity;
}
#content.fadeMe {
  opacity:.4;
  z-index:-1;
}

// Javascript
function firstAction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('firstDiv'),
      elemTwo = document.getElementById('secondDiv');
  elem.className = 'overlay moveUp';
  elemTwo.className = "overlay moveDown";
} 

function secondAction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('secondDiv'),
      main = document.getElementById('content');
  elem.className = 'overlay moveUp';
  main.className = '';
}
```

Edited to add browser prefixes

Edited again because apparently Safari doesn't like pixels and percents mixed

Comment: Zeaklous I will try this out =)

Comment: Zeaklous I tried but it didn't work. It's just showing a blank page when I view it in browser. Can you please elaborate what should I do with the browser prefixes? Do I have to modify something inside the HTML, CSS, JS files?

Comment: What browser are you using? I just updated it again to account for an error in Safari

Comment: I'm using chrome and safari. I'll try your update and will post an update.